# How to hide my badge if the value of the counter is 0?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is the html code, containing the badge and the condition to display the badge

```
<v-tab ripple>
  <v-badge color="red">
    <template v-slot:badge v-if="invoiceCounter > 0 && hasEditAccess === true"> 
      <span>{{ invoiceCounter }}</span>
    </template>
    Invoicing
  </v-badge>
</v-tab>
    
data() {
  return {
    hasEditAccess: false,
    invoiceCounter: 0,              
  };
},
```

Comment: Are you using twig for template rendering?

Comment: If i am getting your question right. You can simply use a `v-if` What is your goal ? What are trying to do ? Elaborate a little.

Comment: If my invoiceCounter is 0,i want the badge to dissapear.Before,with the previous version of vueetify was working.I upgraded to 2.0,and even if my invoiceCounter is 0,it appears the badge.

Answer (score 5):

This hasn't received much activity since posted but I ran into this problem today and figured it out. According to the documentation for the v-badge (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-badge/#props-value) the value property can be used for this. The v-badge **value** prop "Controls whether the component is visible or hidden". So you would do something like this:

```
<v-tab ripple>
  <v-badge color="red" :value="invoiceCounter > 0 && hasEditAccess === true">
    <template v-slot:badge> 
      <span>{{ invoiceCounter }}</span>
    </template>
    Invoicing
  </v-badge>
</v-tab>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the documentation has been updated, and now the property for that is `model-value`.

This works for me without using slots:

```
<v-badge :content="itemsCount" :model-value="itemsCount > 0" color="orange-lighten-2">
    <v-btn>
        Cart
    </v-btn>
</v-badge>
```

In my case:

- `content` shows how many items were added to a cart
- `model-value` will show the badge only when there are items added
- the badge is shown at the top right corner of my Cart button